# why this Sql query is getting stuck?

Tags: oracle

i am trying to edit a row from front-end and query is getting stuck , the query is running fine without `UPPER` but as i applied `upper` it got stuck without any error

query is as follows :

```
String editquery = "UPDATE ENV_SERVER_DETAILS SET " +
   "SERVER_NAME=? , HOPBOX_IP=? , ENV_NAME=? , REGION=? , PASSWORD=? , DELETE_FLAG='Y' , SUPERUSER=? , SUPERPASSW=? ," +
    " COMPONENT='' , SPECIFICATION_OR_DBNAME=? , IP_ADDRESS=? , COMMENTS='' , LAST_UPDATED_BY=? ," +
    "LAST_UPDATED_ON=to_date(to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ," +
    "OTHER_DETAILS=? " +
    "WHERE UPPER(SERVER_NAME) = UPPER(?) and MOTS_ID = ?";
```

i have applied `upper` because some servers in DB are in lower case

Comment: more explanation for "getting stuck" please..........

Comment: Does "stuck" mean it's taking much longer than you expect? How long does it normally take, and how long is it taking now - or is it never returning? If it's slower it's likely to be because you're stopping an index being used (which sagi's answer addresses really); if it never returns are you sure the affected rows are not locked by an update from another session?

Comment: taking a hell lot of time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can suggest adding an `INDEX` on the `UPPER` format of this column:

```
CREATE INDEX SERVER_NAME ON ENV_SERVER_DETAILS (UPPER(SERVER_NAME));
```

The problem is that even if there's an index on this column, the `UPPER` is eliminating the use of it, therefore - the query is slow.

That is if by 'stuck' you mean slow.